# How to retrieve the files under a website directory which forbids access

Tags: python

i need to print all the files under a website's directory.
The directory of the website is :

```
http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/screenshots/e/eclipse/
```

This is the path of the file which is under the directory :

```
http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/screenshots/e/eclipse/9128_large.png
```

For doing it, i write this code :

```
import os
import urllib

url = "http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/screenshots/e/eclipse/"

data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
content_of_directory = os.listdir(data)

print (content_of_directory[0])
print (content_of_directory[1])
```

It gives the following error message :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "retrieve_files_from_web_directory.py", line 11, in <module>
        content_of_directory = os.listdir(data)
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<html>\r\n<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.2.1</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to HTTP, where the concepts of "directory" and "file" don't actually exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can not, the Directory Listing is disabled and you won't be able to list the contents unless you'd know the exact url to a specific file in this location, (like the one you've mentioned)

```
http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/screenshots/e/eclipse/9128_large.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, that's the whole point of forbid the access